# How to find the zeros of an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, matlab

I am having trouble finding the roots of an integral.

For example $F(c)=\int_a^b{(x^2-c^2)}dx$ for some finite interval $[a,b]$.

The problem is that I am trying to do this using numerical analysis.  Obviously the functions is easily integrated.

I guess what I am really trying to ask is what happens if we can not find an antiderivative of the integral how do we find the roots of the integral.

Also is there a routine in matlab one could run to accomplish such a task.

Comment: Newton's method works the same way presuming you know what the derivative of your particular $F$ is.

Answer (score 1):

POSSIBLE HINT: If $f$ is integrable in the domain $(a,b)$, the primitive function $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t),dt$ is continuous.

If you want to find $x_0$ such that $F(x_0)=0$ and you cannot compute $F$ explicitely, an idea is to use the theorem that says that if $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$ have different signs, then there exists $\alpha<\gamma<\beta$ such that $F(\gamma)=0$.

Comment: Which implies one could use bisection method to find F(x)=0.  Still run into the problem of finding F(a),F(b) of different sign.  I was trying to find a method instead of just guessing when two integral signs differ and proceeding with bisection method. Thank you@AndreaMori

Comment: @user101388: Well, since $F(x)$ can be geometrically interpreted as the algebraic sum of the areas defined by the graph of $f$ above and below the $x$-axis, a general information about the behaviour of $f$ may give some hint about the sign of $F(x)$. E.g. if $f$ oscillates with high positive and negative peaks, $F$ may change sign often.